# Android write arabic characters on EditText

Tags: android, android-emulator, arabic, android-2.2-froyo

i build an Android application, it allows the user to answer questions, the user can write the answer in arabic language, but android EditText doesn't allow that, i am using android(2.2), how can i allow the user to write arabic on edittext?

#### Edit

i want arabic character on emulator

Answer (score -1):

Check out this site. It explains all about the ability of implementing different languages in your app. It involves providing different string resources for each locale you want to support.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html